# Como identificar classes iguais em ordem numérica com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Na minha página eu tenho dezenas de botões que, quando clicados, mudam o link (`href`) de um elemento `a`, com o método `attr`. Para evitar colocar uma classe em cada botão, pois são muitos, gostaria que o jQuery identificasse os botões com a classe `.mudar` por ordem numérica.

Como eu tentei:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mudar")[0].click(function(){
    $("#download").attr("href", "https://file1.zip");
  });
  $(".mudar")[1].click(function(){
    $("#download").attr("href", "https://file2.zip");
  });
  $(".mudar")[2].click(function(){
    $("#download").attr("href", "https://file3.zip");
  });
});


<a href="" id="download">baixar</a>

<button class="mudar">zip 1</button>
<button class="mudar">zip 2</button>
<button class="mudar">zip 3</button>
```

Não funcionou porque não entendo como isso funciona. Podem me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o índice através do `index()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mudar").click(function(){
    var indice = $(this).index();
    $("#download").attr("href", "https://file"+indice+".zip");
  });
});
```

No seu caso em específico, você também poderia pegar o número que contém na string e alterar o link através dele:

```
var indice = $(this).html().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
```

**Edição**

Após comentários e conversas no chat criei essa solução:

Primeiro coloque o nome dos arquivos na tag `name` dos botões e um `p` com o nome do arquivo personalizado que será feito o download:

```
<button name="file1" class="mudar">zip 1 <p style="display: none">azul</p></button>
<button name="file2" class="mudar">zip 2 <p style="display: none">preto</p></button>
<button name="file3" class="mudar">zip 3 <p style="display: none">amarelo</p></button>
```

Depois use este código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mudar").click(function(){
    var file = $(this).attr("name");
    var nameFile = $(this).find('p').html();
    var download = $("#download");
    download.attr("href", "https://"+file+".zip");
    download.attr("download", nameFile);
  });
});
```

Comment: Amigão, ficaria ótimo assim, o problema é que só no meu exemplo que os arquivos (1.zip, 2.zip, 3.zip) seguem esse padrão, na real são arquivos com nomes diferentes, apenas as classes que realmente são iguais... Mas eu tenho a opção dos arquivos também em ordem numérica, o problema é que precisaria que eles fossem renomeados quando fossem chamados pra download, tipo o download="nome do arquivo" que pode ser posto na tag <a>. Então, basicamente, ou preciso que seja possível personalizar os links de cada um ou o nome dos arquivos quando forem baixados. Tem alguma solução pra isso?

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra vou criar um solução...

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra dá uma olhada na edição

Comment: Andrei, valeuuu, mas ainda resta um problema kkkk É o seguinte, vamos dizer que eu tenho arquivos: 1.zip, 2.zip, 3.zip etc... eu preciso que quando forem baixados seus nomes sejam mudados pra, exemplo, preto.zip, azul.zip, amarelo.zip. Eu podia fazer isso acontecer, por exemplo, assim: <a href="1.zip" download="preto">. Porque aí, quando ele fosse baixado, ia aparecer preto.zip para o usuário. Dá pra entender? Outra forma que poderia usar, seria os arquivos já com os nomes neles, mas ai não ia conseguir usar essa tua solução pra pegar eles por um padrão...

Comment: Por exemplo, se ali em "name" pegasse o que tivesse escrito lá e colocado antes de .zip... uma lógica tipo $("#download").attr("href", "https://"+name+".zip"). Daria super certo!

Comment: Meu htm seria:<button name="preto" class="mudar">zip 1</button>
<button name="azul" class="mudar">zip 2</button>
<button name="amarelo" class="mudar">zip 3</button>

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra não estou entendo o que você quer...

Comment: Você quer 3 tipos de valores diferentes para cada download? Porque isso?

Comment: Posso te chamar no chat?

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra sim

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87132/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-thiago-soubra).